# Missing module in Javascript but not in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm coding a vscode extension following the guide and I came accross an import problem in my server.ts file. Here is the file tree:

```
test
 ┣ client
 ┃ ┣ out
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
 ┃ ┣ package-lock.json
 ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┗ tsconfig.json
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┣ out
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┣ completions.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ parser.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┗ server.ts
 ┃ ┣ package-lock.json
 ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┣ tsconfig.json
 ┃ ┗ yarn.lock
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ tsconfig.json
```

Which is the same structrure as the extension sample [provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/lsp-sample/tsconfig.json).

However, in server.ts, I'm trying to import some elements from the vscode module:

```js
//server.ts

import { workspace as Workspace } from 'vscode';

let sm_home: string = Workspace.getConfiguration("sourcepawnLanguageServer").get("sourcemod_home");
...
```

and in my package.json, I have:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^5.0.30",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.14.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "vscode-languageserver": "^7.0.0",
    "vscode-languageserver-textdocument": "^1.0.1",
    "vscode-test": "1.5.1",
    "vscode-uri": "^3.0.2"
  },
```

The whole project compiles fine, but when I start the extension, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\Charles\CloudStation\Documents\Perso\Dev\sourcepawn-vscode\server\out\server.js
    at Function._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:15)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:27
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12738)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1079:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Charles\CloudStation\Documents\Perso\Dev\sourcepawn-vscode\server\out\server.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1199:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1039:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:932:14 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'c:\\Users\\Charles\\CloudStation\\Documents\\Perso\\Dev\\sourcepawn-vscode\\server\\out\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

And the error goes away if I remove the import and the line using the import in the `server.ts` file.
This import works fine in `` index.ts` Could this be due to the fact that `` server.ts`is called inside of`index.ts` ?

```js
import { ExtensionContext, workspace as Workspace, window, commands } from 'vscode';
import { LanguageClient, LanguageClientOptions, ServerOptions, TransportKind } from 'vscode-languageclient/node';
import * as glob from 'glob';
import * as path from 'path';

export const sm_home: string = 'Workspace.getConfiguration("sourcepawnLanguageServer").get("sourcemod_home")';

export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    let serverModule = context.asAbsolutePath(
        path.join('server', 'out', 'server.js')
...
```

This doesn't seem to bother [the C/C++ extension.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/main/Extension/src/LanguageServer/client.ts#L8)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what's going on after a while:

Using `vscode` in a language server instance inside a vscode extension doesn't work because (from what I understand) the server doesn't run alongside vscode like the extension does.

If you need settings, workspace's uris etc, you should use `connection.workspace...`, but keep in mind that the requests will be asynchronous.

See an example of how to create a `connection` object [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Where do you get the 'connection' instance?

Answer (score 1):

The [`vscode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode) package has been deprecated. It has now been split up into two packages which are [`@types/vscode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vscode) and [`vscode-test`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-test). The reason for this refactoring can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_splitting-vscode-package-into-typesvscode-and-vscodetest).

You have included the `@types/vscode` dependency but not `vscode-test`.

Adding the `vscode-test` dependency should fix your issue i.e.

```
npm i vscode-test
```

Also ensure you have:

```
"engines": { "vscode": "^1.32.0" }
```

defined in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, unfortunately this doesn't work, I still get the same error, I edited the package.json file in the question accordingly.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but have you definetly installed you dependencies? e.g. `npm install`

Comment: Just checked, and yes, I ran `npm install` after deleting every `node_modules` folders, and the folders were recreated.

Comment: Ok, another thing to try is making sure you have `"engines": {"vscode": "^1.32.0"},` in your package.json. Making this suggestion as the code is importing from 'vscode'.

Comment: Made sure of that as well, but I know where the problem comes from now, what I am trying to do won't work because I'm importing `vscode` from a language server instance.